# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ k = \frac{1+4n}{5}, \qquad (k \in \mathbb{Z} )$

Tags: trigonometry, divisibility

My question is rather general but I got stuck in that issue after trying to solve a trigonometric equation.

After simplifying I got this:

$$\sin \left(\frac{5x}{4}\right) + \cos x = 2$$

which is true if and only if

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\sin \left(\frac{5x}{4}\right) &= 1\\
\cos x &= 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Hence

\begin{align*}
\cos x &= 1 \\
\implies x &= 2\pi k, \qquad (k \in \mathbb{Z} )
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\sin \left(\frac{5x}{4}\right) &= 1\\
\implies \frac{5x}{4} &= \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{5} + \frac{8\pi n}{5},\qquad (n \in \mathbb{Z} )
\end{align*}

Thus the solutions are

\begin{align*}
2\pi k &= \frac{2\pi}{5} + \frac{8\pi n}{5}\\
k &= \frac{1+4n}{5}, \qquad (k \in \mathbb{Z} )
\end{align*}

Here I'm stuck. Clearly the constraint of $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is not true for all $n$'s. $n$ has to be made up of some number $m$ that makes the numerator divisible by $5$. The answer that I'm given says that $n = 5m + 1$, which makes sense but I don't know how to get there. And what if, just to say, $\displaystyle k = \frac{8+13n}{7}$?

Thanks!!

Comment: @JDrinas $n = 5m + 1$ is the answer that my textbook gives for $k$ to be an integer, I don't know how to get such result. By eyeballing I got the same thing but I've been unsuccessfully trying to find a general way to do it and avoid guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not familiar with congruences, you can look at it this way: If $4n+1$ is divisible by $5$, then there is some integer $r$ with $4n+1 = 5r$, so that $4n = 5r-1$ and then $4n-4=5r-5$. Factoring both sides gives $4(n-1) = 5(r-1)$. Since $4$ and $5$ are relatively prime, it follows that $5$ divides $n-1$; that is, $n-1 = 5s$ for some integer $s$ and thus $n = 1+5s$.

Comment: Nice!. That makes sense. I'll have a look at that thing of congruences. Thanks.

Comment: You can also just look at the equation $4n+1=5r$ and start to write down values of $n$ for which this holds in integers. You'll quickly see that it is just values of $n$ that end in $1$ or $6$; that is, that leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $5$. This is the same as saying that $n\equiv 1\mod{5}$. (Of course, what I just described is not a proof, but you might want to think of it as  a poor man's introduction to what congruences mean).

Answer (score 1):

$k$ is an integer if and only if $n=5m+1$ for some $m\in \mathbb Z$

To see this, solve the equation $$4n+1\equiv 0\ (\ mod\ 5\ )$$

This is equivalent to $$4n-4=4(n-1)\equiv 0\ (\ mod\ 5)$$ , which immediately
implies that $n\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ 5\ )$ is necessary and sufficient.

Comment: After watching some videos I've understood what you mean. Since $n \equiv 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 5)$ it follows that, for some integer $m$, $n-1 = 5m$ or $n = 5m +1$. Cool. Thanks (:.

Answer (score 0):

$4n+1$ divisible by 5 $\Leftrightarrow 4n+1 \equiv_{5} 0  \Leftrightarrow -n \equiv_{5} -1 \Leftrightarrow n \equiv_{5} 1$ So n is an integer of the form $1+5q$ for abitrary integer $q$.